# 2000/100 , I want output 2000 (strings before /)

Tags: sql, oracle

help to get output as 2000 where input value is 2000/100

I want whole strings before /

```
input 2000/100
output 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple options (based on what you described):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2000/100' from dual)
  3  select col,
  4    regexp_substr(col, '\w+')           option_1,
  5    substr(col, 1, instr(col, '/') - 1) option_2
  6  from test;

COL      OPTION_1 OPTION_2
-------- -------- --------
2000/100 2000     2000

SQL>
```